# Counting number of ways to buy items

Tags: combinatorics

> A man buys 240 items for \$250 at a store. There are 3 types of items: A (\$15), B (\$1) and C (25¢). He buys at least one of each. How many solutions?

I am working on this problem for a programming logic class. I have already completed a program, but I want to find a way to check if it is correct or not. I got four solutions:

```
A = 2 bought, B = 214 bought, C = 24 bought: Solution #1
A = 5 bought, B = 155 bought, C = 80 bought: Solution #2
A = 8 bought, B = 96 bought, C = 136 bought: Solution #3
A = 11 bought, B = 37 bought, C = 192 bought: Solution #4
```

I am solving it using two for loops (in Javascript). First loop = number of object A (from 1 to 13), second loop = number of object B (from 1 to 234). Then, I fill the rest in with object C, and I print whatever equals 250$. I believe I have the right answer, but I would like to figure out an equation to check it. The number of solutions is between 1 and 50.

Comment: I have placed your question in the body. The question text shouldn't be in the title only. A way to solve this would be with generating functions.

Comment: Functions in what sense?

Comment: No, that's the phrase - a _generating function_ is an object that can be used to represent a sequence. Or, in this case, solve the problem of partitions. I'm trying to construct an answer using this technique. For an introduction, see Wilf's text: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$15a+b+\frac14 c = 250\tag 1$

$a+b+c = 240 \tag 2$

Subtracting eq(2) from eq(1) to eliminate $b$ and multiplying by $4$ to get rid of fractions, we get $56a -  3c = 40  \tag3$

This is now a [Diophantine equation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-diophantine-equations-one-equation/#:%7E:text=A%20Diophantine%20equation%20is%20a,degree%20equation%20of%20this%20type.), which we can rewrite as

$c =  18a -13 + \frac {2a-1}3 \tag4$

It is easy to see that the lowest possible positive integral value of $a$ is $2$, and you should now be able to fill in the blanks for this particular solution, and proceed further.

Also, yes, the $4$ solutions you obtained are correct.

Comment: good job friend $+1$

Comment: @SalmonFish: Thanks, good to see you after a long time ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: @trueblueanil This is very interesting, but I don't understand how you got from step 2 to 3 and 4 (eliminating B and creating those last two equations).

Comment: @rootbeer2017: To go from step 2 to step 3, subtract equation(2) from equation (1) and multiply the result by 4 to get rid of fractions. From step 3 to step 4, you must know how to  get $c = \frac{56a-40} 3$, and then you separate it into the integer part, and the fraction part.

Answer (score 2):

As it is indicated in comments , you can use generating functions as alternative ways. To do this , lets use the exponents of $x's$ as cost of product , and use the exponent of $a's$ as the number of items.

As @trueblueanil mentioned , we can say that $60A +4B+C=1000$ by multiply both side of $15A+B+(1/4)C=250$ by $4$

Then ,

- Generating function for type **A** : $$a^1x^{60}+a^2x^{120}+a^3x^{180}+...+a^kx^{60k}+...= \frac{ax^{60}}{1-ax^{60}}$$
- Generating function for type **B** : $$a^1x^{4}+a^2x^{8}+a^3x^{12}+...+a^kx^{4k}+...= \frac{ax^4}{1-ax^4}$$
- Generating function for type **C** : $$a^1x^{1}+a^2x^{2}+a^3x^{3}+...+a^kx^{k}+...= \frac{ax}{1-ax}$$

Now , find the coefficient of $a^{240}x^{1000}$ in the expansion of $$\bigg(\frac{ax^{60}}{1-ax^{60}}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{ax^4}{1-ax^4}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{ax}{1-ax}\bigg)$$

I think you can find it using your programming skills.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the G.F. answer, you're back in full form ! +1